# How to display attributes SKUs and Description above Add to Cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WordPress WooCommerce. I have a requirement to display SKU and Description of ATTRIBUTES above Add To Cart button on Product page.

Right now Description is above the button and SKU is below the button.

**Current result**

[image]

How can I display them above the button? Also, right now Description appears after selecting Product Variables, I want it to display all the time, just it can change upon changing selection.

**Expected result**

[image: expected]

I checked in WooCommerce template files, there are different PHP files for displaying both SKUs and Attr Desc.

Comment: Current Result : https://nimb.ws/IPXmSJ
Expected Result : https://nimb.ws/X1rotC

Comment: I added your actual images to the question for better readability.